# RabbitMQ - notification if message is waiting too long in queue

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

Is there a way how to get notification from RabbitMQ if a message is waiting in queue for a long time?

Comment: Tahnk you, your answer helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common and standard solution to ensure that a delivery latency requirement is met is to set a [Time To Live (TTL)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) on the message, and if this expires, this will be moved to the Dead Letter Queue where you can perform compensating actions.

TTL can be defined

- On a [per-message](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl-in-publishers) basis by the message publisher
- As a default on the [queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-queue-message-ttl) itself

If both the queue and the message have the TTL set, then the lower latency will be policed.